# Автоматическая генерация ресурсов (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Приветствую всех!
Возникла такая ситуация, что я описал множество настроек в xml файле и указал ссылки на несуществующие строки. Подскажите, есть ли способ автоматической генерации ресурсов(в моём случае - строк)? Никак не могу найти.
Среда разработки - Eclipse.
[image]

Comment: Я посоветую перейти на intellij idea от jet brains :) они ее год назад сделали бесплатной и там есть и это, и много других плюшек, которых нет в eclipse

Comment: кого они сделали бесплатным? в 12 версии только появился удобный хмл редактор для андроида... хотя я соглашусь что штука классная )

Comment: чем он удобней 11? тем что там появилась визуальная часть, где можно перетаскивать мышкой? :D ИМХО быстрей руками набрать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй выбрать строку, а дальше

> Refactor --> Android --> Extract Android String.

Comment: Попробовал, вот как Eclipse на это отвечает:  http://s018.radikal.ru/i527/1303/59/c3a92dd71e41.png